# Why am I getting GKVoiceChatServiceUnableToConnectError? What's wrong?

Tags: iphone, voice, gamekit

I'm trying to implement GK's voice chat. I have the underlying network done over wifi instead of bluetooth. Between the simulator and my test device, I was able to accept the invitation. But immediately after, I get the call didNotStartWithParticipantID, with the following error:

```
Error Domain=GKVoiceChatServiceErrorDomain Code=32002 UserInfo=0x3b286f0 "Network conditions prevented connection."
```

Any ideas? What's causing this?